# How can I add custom fields to Commerce Discounts?

Tags: commerce

We would like to add a long text description and an image to each Commerce Discount which we will display to Users.

How do I do this, since the Discount data structures are not available in the Admin?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement the field api to attach fields to certain entities.  Or you could within hook_entity_info() (I think), there is a 'fieldable' array key you could set to TRUE.  From there, you may need to programmatically add a field to it.  A good way to get field definition code is to use Field Inspector module, add a field to an entity using the UI, and export that field definition as a base to code yours.

Comment: THANKS! So are you saying that if one makes the entity 'fieldable' it magically appears in the Admin Content UI so that one can add fields there?

Comment: Not exactly.  Since I don't have a site with Commerce Discount on it:  if you do a hook-entity-info-alter() and set that to TRUE, if there was already a uri path to manage that discount (think manage fields/manage display), it may allow you to add fields that way.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1124722  Should explain it better than I.

Comment: Got it. I see how to add a field programmatically... which seems like a LOT less work than writing all the code just so that I can -then- do the same thing via UI.